# Why does my scripts return error 500?

Tags: javascript, url, path

This is not really an issue but it bothers me a bit :)

Long story short: My scripts are not loading due to the source URL which is like :

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/Content/javascript/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.example.com/Content/javascript/min/head-full-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
....
```

When I put the url in my browser it shows a 500 internal error. But if I modify "Content" to "content", the scripts are correctly loaded and everything is fine.
I have 2 colleagues who have no issue ("Content" & "content" are working for them). I checked the path of the scripts which is like `.../Content/javascript/...`

The solution is obvious but does anyone have an idea about my issue ? Can someone else be impacted due this change : "Conten" -> "content" ?

PS: I tested with IE 11, Firefox 39 & Chrome 43, same issue for the 3

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like there is a bug in your server... if the file isn't found, it should return a 404, not a 500 error, and your server should probably be smart enough to not depend on the name sensitivity (or insensitivity) of your filesystem, which I suspect is the underlying issue.

Comment: [500 Internal Server Error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1): The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request

Comment: Sure but how explain that my 2 other colleagues don't have the same issue with the same URL as me ? (We are working on similar browsers)

Comment: *Unpacking his crystal ball* Because... How we are supposed to diagnose the problem your server has with the request from your client? Check the server logs, debug on the server, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

There are several options you can try to fix it:
1.Reload the web page. You can do that by clicking the refresh/reload button, pressing F5, or trying the URL again from the address bar.
2.Clear your browser's cache. If there's a problem with the cached version of the page you're viewing, it could be causing HTTP 500 issues.
3.Delete your browser's cookies. Some 500 Internal Server Error issues can be corrected by deleting the cookies associated with the site you're getting the error on.

Try these options and check if they seem to make a difference.
```